# How to make BLOB work on Oracle and PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I have entity with a `BLOB` column:

```
@Lob
@Column(name = "SRC")
private byte[] src;
```

My application works with two databases, Oracle and PostgreSQL. When I start the application with Oracle as written above, all works fine, but when I start with PostgreSQL, I get an error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [src] in table [catalogs]; found [bytea (Types#BINARY)], but expecting [oid (Types#BLOB)]
```

After that I read articles and advice in Google and fix it:

```
@Lob
@Type(type="org.hibernate.type.BinaryType")
@Column(name = "SRC")
private byte[] src;
```

Now it works fine with PostgreSQL, but with Oracle I get exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [src] in table [catalogs]; found [blob (Types#BLOB)], but expecting [raw(255) (Types#VARBINARY)]
```

What should I do to make it work on both databases?

P.S. I have similar problems with CLOB

Comment: Do you use suitable drivers in your `DataSource` / `JPA configuration` for each database?

Comment: of course. I have separate profiles for configuration. There are dependencies for drivers and `oracle` and `postgresql`.

Comment: Hmmm.. try add `columnDefinition = "VARBINARY"` attribute to your `@Column` annotation and let check what's happen. Do two cases: with and without `@Type` annotation.

Comment: It is not helped

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately hibernate entities are db-provider specific.

Comment: So much for the promised database independence. This is extremely easy to deal with on JDBC level, so why can't Hibernate do that?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yea, hibernate itself is independent. I guess the JDBC makes the entitie-classes incooperative here. You might write a wrapper-driver that wrapps the postgres-driver to have a behave like oracle in order to use the oracle-style-hibernate-entity-classes (vice versa a wrapper for the oracle-driver to have a behave like postgres in order to use the postgres-style-hibernate-entity-classes).

Answer (score -1):

your sql type should be : bytea (Postgres database)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).